# Stick multiple posts in a single category

Tags: categories, sticky-post

How to stick multiple posts in a single category to show on top of that category?

**Tried Ideas:**
I tried to use "Category Sticky Post" plugin, but it only allows me to pin one post for each category.

Also tried to stick posts to the homepage, and remove the featured posts from the home page, but they don't stick on top of the category.

Comment: What have you already attempted?

Comment: "Category Sticky Post" plugin, but it only allows me to pin one post for each category. Also tried to stick posts to homepage, and remove the featured posts from the home page, but they don't stick on top of the category.

Comment: Most simple method is to change date of publication and sort posts in category how you need..

Comment: true .. but I need to change the time each time I -or any other editor- add a new post ... which isn't that much practical !! but thanx tho !!

Comment: @DavidKlhufek, changing the date is absolutly not a good practice, because Google can misunderstand your intentions ([read this](http://www.thesempost.com/google-potential-spam-issues-changing-article-dates/)). Even worse you are changing the URL of the post if the permalink contains the data; this could impact very negatively your SEO if you don't redirect the old URL to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `category.php` should have two loops — one for stickies, one for regular posts:

```
<?php
// get sticky posts array
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');

// First WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    // include stickies
    'post__in'  => $sticky
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// First loop for stickies only
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() );

    echo get_the_title() . '<br />';
    echo get_the_content() . '<br />';

endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_postdata(); // don't forget to reset before the next loop

/***************************************/

// Second WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    // exclude stickies
    'post__not_in' => $sticky
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Second loop for posts excluding stickies
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() );

    echo get_the_title() . '<br />';
    echo get_the_content() . '<br />';

endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_postdata(); // if necessary
```

More than likely, you will need a lot of additional `WP_Query` parameters.

- See [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query);
- See [Sticky Posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts)

Comment: working great .. had to add few parameters ... but managed to work it out